# How to find nth p element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find the 3rd `p tag` of each category, based on first p tag's value. 
e.g. The first p tag value is `Tie`, then find the quantity of it.

If the html element tree should be formatted in a better way, I am open to it. The html for all `ul` is written from code behind at C# to load items from database.

```
$("#wel div ").each(function(index, element) {   
    if ($(this).('p:nth-of-type(1)').html() == "Tie")
    {
        $(this).('p:nth-of-type(3)').css('background-color','red');
    }
}


<div id="fel">Category1
    <ul>
    <li>
        <div >
            <p>Shirt</p>
            <p>Price:$25</p>
            <p>Quantity:20</p> <!--find this?-->
        </div>
        </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <p>Tie</p>
            <p>Price:$10</p>
            <p>Quantity:10</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <p>Trousers</p>
            <p>Price:$50</p>
            <p>Quantity:5</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="wel">Category2 
<ul>
    <li>
        <div >
            <p>Shirt</p>
            <p>Price:$25</p>
            <p>Quantity:20</p>
        </div>
        </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <p>Tie</p>
            <p>Price:$10</p>
            <p>Quantity:10</p><!--find this?-->
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <p>Trousers</p>
            <p>Price:$50</p>
            <p>Quantity:5</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

---

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79xbw2uq/1/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can 2 top level elements with different ids `fel` and `wel` so need to use `#wel div, #fel div` to find the category `div` elements, then need to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find the `p`

```js
$("#wel div, #fel div").each(function (index, element) {
    if ($(this).find('p:nth-of-type(1)').html().trim() == "Tie") {
        $(this).find('p:nth-of-type(3)').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fel">Category1
  <li>
    <div>
      <p>Shirt</p>
      <p>Price:$25</p>
      <p>Quantity:20</p>
      <!--find this?-->
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <p>Tie</p>
      <p>Price:$10</p>
      <p>Quantity:10</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <p>Trousers</p>
      <p>Price:$50</p>
      <p>Quantity:5</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
<div id="wel">Category2
  <li>
    <div>
      <p>Shirt</p>
      <p>Price:$25</p>
      <p>Quantity:20</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <p>Tie</p>
      <p>Price:$10</p>
      <p>Quantity:10</p>
      <!--find this?-->
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <p>Trousers</p>
      <p>Price:$50</p>
      <p>Quantity:5</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

---

You can also do

```
$("#wel div, #fel div ").each(function (index, element) {
    var $ps = $(this).find('p');
    if ($ps.eq(0).html().trim() == "Tie") {
        $ps.eq(2).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tctdan25/2/)

Comment: faire un carton!!! Clean. I also learn how to approach and ask a question in html, javascript space, to get the right answer. What I need is to find within one particular category. So most likely I have to provide the div id.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the generic way of doing it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var div = $('p:contains("Tie")').parent()
    $('p:contains("Tie")').parent()
    var price = $(div).find("p:contains('Price')").css('background-color','red');
    console.log(price)

});
```

Please refer the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/77e24hug/)

Comment: Can this give the parent div's id using `attr('id')`? (e.g. #wel)